# /etc/rc.d/postgres start vs rc.d postgres start

Tags: arch-linux, services, postgresql

What's the difference between those two commands?

```
/etc/rc.d/postgres start
```

and

```
rc.d postgres start
```

Aren't those interchangeable?

I tried starting PostgreSQL using the latter, but it only works with the first one.

I'm using Sys V init on Arch Linux.

Comment: What distribution are you running? What init system are you using (if you don't understand this bit, we'll assume the default)? There are multiple service management systems under Linux, and the commands to start and stop services are different.

Comment: @Gilles Sys V init on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that you have your your syntax a bit backwards.

```
rc.d                                                                                
usage: rc.d action daemon ...

e.g: rc.d list
     rc.d help
     rc.d start sshd gpm
```

So you would want to do

```
rc.d start postgresql
```

The rc.d script is simply for convenience. It makes starting multiple services from the command line easier.  So you can do things like

```
rc.d start lighttpd postgresql
```

Instead of manually having to call both like

```
/etc/rc.d/lighttpd start
/etc/rc.d/postgresql start
```

Comment: oh, that must be it, sorry about that.